# Unreal Engine 4 destroy actor (Brush)

Tags: unreal-engine4

I have a simple blueprint, which destroys the actors between the camera and the character:

[image: Blueprint]

And the top-down template a bit changed:

[image: Map]

The sphere is a static mesh and the blueprint does work on it:

[image: Static mesh]

The other boxes are Brush type and the blueprint DOESN'T work on them.

[image]

Any idea?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BSP brushes are not to be used in the final gameplay, they are just there for you to quickly create the level geometry. Once you are ready to ship your game you should convert all brushes to static meshes to prevent errors such as this.